# Which are the hashing technique in php other than openssl_pbkdf2, hash_pbkdf2?

Tags: php, hash, password-encryption, sha512

Which hashing method is used to hash the word 'sb@123' to get the hash `$pbkdf2-sha512$25000$iTGGMAbg3FsLgdD6X8u59w$LXi2AGKllnsYpfyR0M0aQZTvF2EwhwEI4elKXehjNzy2ZL8Q.w.wceJiIq45PFAjb9QWHmzeQzr3GdZr83qjMA`

openssl_pbkdf2
hash_pbkdf2

```
openssl_pbkdf2('sb@123', 'iTGGMAbg3FsLgdD6X8u59w, 64, 25000, 'sha512');
hash_pbkdf2("sha512", 'sb@123', 'iTGGMAbg3FsLgdD6X8u59w, 25000, 64);
```

Answer (score 0):

As this example shows, both those functions will produce the same output with identical inputs:

```php
$salt = base64_decode("iTGGMAbg3FsLgdD6X8u59w");
$hash1_base64 = base64_encode(hash_pbkdf2("sha512", 'sb@123', $salt, 25000, 64, TRUE));
echo $hash1_base64 . "\n";

$hash2_base64 = base64_encode(openssl_pbkdf2('sb@123', $salt, 64, 25000, "sha512"));
echo $hash2_base64 . "\n";
```

produces output

```
LXi2AGKllnsYpfyR0M0aQZTvF2EwhwEI4elKXehjNzy2ZL8Q+w+wceJiIq45PFAjb9QWHmzeQzr3GdZr83qjMA==
LXi2AGKllnsYpfyR0M0aQZTvF2EwhwEI4elKXehjNzy2ZL8Q+w+wceJiIq45PFAjb9QWHmzeQzr3GdZr83qjMA==
```

which matches the output you have provided.